# Javascript datepicker pop up window not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My java script date picker popup window is not appearing when clicked on the text box. I tried almost 8 different date picker's none of them are working.

```
<tr>
<td >Date Of Birth</td>
<td ><input name="bdate" type="text" id="datepick2" disabled="disabled"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepickr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new datepickr('datepick');
    new datepickr('datepick2', {
        'dateFormat': 'm/d/y'
    });

    new datepickr('datepick3', {
        'fullCurrentMonth': false,
        'dateFormat': 'l, F j'
    });
</script>
</td>
</tr>
```

This is how my code looks. I tried opening in firefox and IE but not working. no errors nothing just doesn't appear when clicked on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's trying it to soon, but without seeing the rest of the code or knowing what plugin you are using, its hard to say for sure.  Try this though:

```
$(function() {
   new datepickr('datepick');
   new datepickr('datepick2', {
    'dateFormat': 'm/d/y'
   });

   new datepickr('datepick3', {
    'fullCurrentMonth': false,
    'dateFormat': 'l, F j'
   });
});
```

That waits for the document.ready event, and then calls the functions.  Or you may need to do

```
$('#id-of-input-you-want').datepickr();
```

Comment: I tried some changes and now its appearing but at the end of the page not in the text box td.

Comment: <input name="bdate" type="text" id="datepick2" disabled="disabled"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="datepickr.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      
   new datepickr('datepick2', {
    'dateFormat': 'm/d/y'
   });
   
  </script>
   </td>

Comment: the above code is wht it looks after changes... i just took one date picker, removed the 2 others.